# standardize area of image with different ratio using css (or javascript)?

Tags: javascript, css, image

I need to display a lot of logos of partners but they don't all have the same ratio. If one logo is larger than one other I'm sure that they'll start complaining ; so I need to find a way to make the area more or less equal. Does someone know of a solution using only css ? (Or javascript if this is not possible in css).

Say I got a 200x200 container for each image, I needed the area of image to be close to 10.000 pixels but not larger/wider than 200px.
Beyond are some inputs and the expected conversions

```
100 x 100   => 100 x 100 = 10k      
1000x 1000  => 100 x 100 = 10k   
200 x 100   => 141 x  70 about 10k  
200 x 400   => 70  x 141 about 10k  
800 x  60   => 200 x  30 = 6000 only but that 's the best that will fit in a 200 x 200 square
```

I guess this is not possible in css so if someone got a javascript solution that's fine too.
(I can't do it server side and I got no control over the uploaded size (or ratios) of images)

Comment: Object fit or background-size will help for getting the same area for image of same ratio (100x100 and 1000x1000) but this won't help for images with distinct ratio. A 2x1 in a 1x1 container will fill 50% of area while a 1x1 will occupy 100%. I'd need both to fill the same area (around 25%)

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, there's no solution in pure css for now. I'd need something like contain(25%) to fill 25% of available area. Maybe some day. After all there was no background-size some years ago.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "sort out" but as I said I don't have control over uploaded images. I just got a json struct with image source and url associated.

Comment: I DON'T (want to) MANAGE THE UPLOAD

Comment: I wrote twice that I got no control over the uploaded size of images so please stop suggesting I should manage it at upload time or postprocess onthe server : I CAN'T.

Comment: You always have control over what is shown on your site - even if they upload images to a server somewhere, you can still use that url and process that raw image. Anyway as you seem to want to be very angry over nothing and people trying to help you, good luck with that, I am out

Comment: No that's me that gives up. You know the context so much better than me...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this method:

```
.logo{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
}

<div class="logo" style="background-image: url('logoA.png');"></div>
<div class="logo" style="background-image: url('logoB.png');"></div>
```

That displays a logo  the biggest size possible. All logo's have equal canvas to be displayed in. If a logo is very wide (or high), thats their problem. A good designer thinks of this ahead in time, for exactly this kind of situation. A common ratio is 4:3.

Some logo's have a variant, which might be a little more square. Whatever you do, *do not do that yourself*! They are responsible for their logo.

---

*Offtopic: This method also works really well for thumbnails for a slideshow :) If you're in a wild mood, background-size:cover;*

Comment: Thank you but I know about background-size and this does not address the problem of "equal area". Load a 200x75 image (or a 400x150) into your solution and it will fill 15000 pixels. Now load a 75x200 and it will fill 28x75 = 2100 pixels = 7 times less pixels. I need roughly the same pixels count for every image.

Answer (score 0):

My javascript solution for now

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".logos");
// read a number (<1) in the fillfactor property of the container
var fillfactor  = parseFloat(container[0].dataset.fillfactor);


var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".logos span");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 var span = spans[i];
 var maxw          = span.clientWidth;
 var maxh          = span.clientHeight; 
 var containerarea = maxw * maxh;
 var desiredarea   = fillfactor * containerarea;
 var img = span.children[0].children[0];
 var w = img.width;
 var h = img.height;
 var area = w*h;
 var factor = Math.sqrt( desiredarea / area);
 var nw = w * factor;
 var nh;
 if (nw > maxw)
 {
  nw = maxw;
  nh = h * (nw/w);
 }
 else
  nh = h * factor;
 if (nh > maxh)
 {
  nh = maxh;
  nw = w * (nh/h);
 }
 img.width  = nw ;
 img.height = nh ;
}
```

```css
.logos:after,
.logosopt:after
{
 content:" ";
 display: block;
 clear:both;
}


.logosopt span img
{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%; 
 object-fit: contain;
}




 span
{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content: center;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border:1px solid red;
 float:left;
}

img {
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sizes using  background-size: contain</h2>
<div class="logosopt">
 <span><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"></span>
 <span><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></span>
 <span><img src="https://infiniteingenuity.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/skyscraper.jpg"></span>
 
</div>

notice the stack overflow logo is bigger (its area is bigger) than the two other ones
<br />

<h2>Images are resized to fill 33% (or less) of area using JS</h2>
<div class="logos" data-fillfactor="0.33">
 <span><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"></a></span>
 <span><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></a></span>
 <span><a href=""><img src="https://infiniteingenuity.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/skyscraper.jpg"></a></span>
</div>
```